# cakephp, cake mail not working

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I tried to send mail using `CakeEmail` but its not working.

My code
`

```
    $Email = new CakeEmail();
    $Email->from(array(Configure::read('site_email') => 'My Site'));
    $Email->to(Configure::read('site_email'));
    $Email->subject('About');
    $Email->send('My message');`
```

My config:

```
`public $default = array(
    'transport' => 'Mail',
    'from' => 'site_email@co.in',
    'charset' => 'utf-8',
    'headerCharset' => 'utf-8'
);`
```

I am using normal mail transport but it showing error as

```
`mail() [<a href='http://php.net/function.mail'>function.mail</a>]: SMTP server response: 553 We do not relay non-local mail, sorry.`
```

i don't know why?

Comment: check these links:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809369/warning-mail-function-mail-smtp-server-response-553-we-do-not-relay-non-l

Comment: I recommend you to *read* error messages, some are cryptic but this one is very clear about what is wrong. Then search on Google for that error message. It is pretty rare that you're the first person ever to encounter a specific error.